# Rewriting url for language selection not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a multilanguage site, I want to rewrite the url such as :

```
www.mySite.com/index.php?lang=de 
www.mySite.com/product.php?id=100&lang=de
```

turns into

```
www.mySite.com/de/index.php
www.mySite.com/de/product.php?id=100
```

I don't want also that my relative links will be not working

This is my .htacess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php  /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: [Handy little .htaccess Tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: your tool doens't work, no display

Comment: It's not my tool just a handy one I use sometimes when I test .htaccess rules :) Thought it might be useful for you at some point.

Comment: What is error you're getting when you enter `www.mySite.com/de/index.php` URL?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/de/index.php  gives <<The requested resource /de/index.php was not found on this server.>>